# how can I construct an string array that would look like this inside memory

Tags: c++, memory

I wan't to construct a string array that would look like this in memory

> Test.Test1.test54.exampleeeee.

the dots being null characters. Is this even posible?

Comment: It is not totally clear what a "string array" means here, but a char array(?) can wery well contain nulls `char array[] = "Test\0Test1\0test54\0exampleeeee";`

Comment: `"Test\0Test1\0test54\0exampleeeee"s` should work fine.

Comment: Here's an array of string:  `std::string array[] = {"Test.\0", "Test1.\0", "test54\0", "exampleeeee\0"};`.

Comment: Please provide a[mre] of how you intend to use the array, once yo created it. That should clarify most of the haziness of the question as asked now.

Comment: *Is this even posible?* -- C++ is used to create games, operating systems, computer-aided designs, control machinery, etc.  Wouldn't it be strange if the answer to your question is "no, C++ can't do this"?

Comment: It is possible, but if you want to pass such data to `std::string`, be wary which constructor it will call. The `(const char*)` constructor (as in `std::string str = "a\0b"`) will stop on first null character (same for calling `std::strlen`), so you will want to operate on ranges (2 pointers or pointer+length).